# "Run on an OS" vs. "run under an OS"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, computing, transitive-verbs

What is the correct way to specify the operating system you are targeting or using?

Is a program running *on* or *under* an operating system (OS)?

Is a machine running an OS or *under* an OS?

Comment: Being a mass noun not a count noun, *software* cannot take an indefinite article, but *a program* can.

Comment: They're just difference metaphorical usages which are both common and both valid. The OS is often called a *platform*, in which case applications run **on** it. But if it's thought of as the machine's "top-level control program", managing all user applications, those apps run **under** it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Machines run operating system software; or run operating systems. My laptop here runs Windows 7.

At least in British English, software can run *on* **or** *under* the OS.

> My program "foo" runs under Windows 7 but fails completely under Windows 8.
>   I still have to test it on Windows Phone 7.

The first sentence might use *under* because it could be *under conditions which include Windows 7*, but using *under* here is normal usage [at least in Britain].

The second sentence could be taken to mean *on a machine running Windows Phone 7*, but since reference to the machine is understood, "on an OS" is fine.

Comment: I think this is the same everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

A machine is *running a certain operating system.*

A program is running *on a certain operating system.*

References and examples:

From the Wikipedia article ["Computer compatibility"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_compatibility):

> Software compatibility can also refer to ability for the software to run on a particular operating system.

From the article about [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux):

> Cell phones and PDAs running Linux on open-source platforms became more common from 2007.

And thus, depending on who your audience is, you can say:

- I'm using Ubuntu Linux
- My PC is running Ubuntu Linux

And

- I'm playing Braid (running)* on Ubuntu Linux
- I was never able to get Adobe Photoshop to run properly on Ubuntu Linux

*the bracketed part is optional, but not necessary

Answer (score -1):

It actually just means what *on* and *under* mean. The software program either runs *under* the OS at a lower-level or *on* the OS at a higher-level.

For example; Microsoft Office runs *on* Windows 7, because it is a high-level software program that requires the services of the OS to function. Where as, the device drivers for a video graphics card run *under* the OS, since the driver provides functionality to the OS at a lower-level.

When you say software is running *under* an OS it implies that software is connecting to services *under* the top layer used by the user. Where as, when you say software is running *on* an OS it implies the software is executing above the top-layer.

I don't think *on* or *under* really make much difference anymore, since operating systems today are so automated, plug-in play and consumer friendly. People no longer need to manage device drivers or services manually. So the differences have been lost over time.

Comment: I don't think normal, everyday usage makes the distinction you propose. A game, for instance, can equally well run "*under* Windows 7" and "*on* Windows 7".

Comment: As a commonly used expression, they both work. It's not something I think is important. I prefer the term "requires". That is more accurate.

Comment: Hmm. I would use "requires" for capabilities — processor speed, that sort of thing —, not for the OS.